# Update price to half (price / 2) in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to update `price` field to `0.5 * price` using mongoose.

what i tried (and works) is finding items, changing them and saving them. but is there any more efficient(better performance) way?

```
Products.find({} ,
  (err, ps) => {
    ps.forEach(p => {
      p.Price = p.Price * 0.5;
      p.save((err, res) => console.log(err, res))
    });
  }
)
```

Note that i know how to do this in mongodb ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field)), but i don't know how to do this in mongoose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$mul](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/mul/) for update document.

```
Products.update({}, { $mul: { price: 0.5} }, { multi: true })
```

You need to use `multi` for multiple products.

If you think to use this [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) or [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field)

```
const products = await Products.find({})
const promiseAll = products.map(async (product) => {
   await Products.findOneAndUpdate(
       { _id: product._id } ,
       { $set: { price: product.price * 0.5 }} 
   );
})
await Promise.all(promiseAll)
```

Or use your promise resolve syntax

Comment: thanks, what if i wanted to use something like: `price = price - discount` (i mean, subtract or add another column value to it?)

Comment: { $set: { price: product.price * 0.5 }} it this line do whatever arthmetic you want to do.

Comment: isn't this performance as slow as the solustion i mentioned in post (because it runs multiple queries) ?

Comment: Performance for yours and this solution is nearly the same. And it is standard of code. No problem with multiple queries and document.

Comment: thanks. i used mysql for years, but new to nosql(like mongo). consider we have 2k products, a query like this was considered `terrible` in mysql. is there any reason that you're saying `No problem with multiple queries`? doesn't running 2k queries consider bad in mongo?

Comment: No matter what. I used this type of query once with 18k record to update.